# nhibernate exception c#

Tags: c#, nhibernate, app-config

i do a simple application with nhibernate:
class utilisateur.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" auto-import="true">
  <class name="nhiber.utilisateur, nhiber" table="utilisateur">
    <id name="login" type="string"></id>
    <property name="password" type="string" />
    <property name="age" type="int" />
    <property name="location" type="string" />
    <property name="name" type="string" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

class utilisateur.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using NHibernate;
using NHibernate.Cfg;
using System.Reflection;

namespace nhiber
{
   public class utilisateur
    {
        public virtual string login { get; set; }
        public virtual string password { get; set; }
        public virtual string name { get; set; }
        public virtual int age { get; set; }
        public virtual string location { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<utilisateur> get_liste_utilisateurs(){
            using (ISession session = OpenSession())
            {
                IQuery query = session.CreateQuery("FROM utilisateur");
                IList<utilisateur> pets = query.List<utilisateur>();
                return pets;
            }
         }
       public static ISessionFactory SessionFactory;
       public static ISession OpenSession()
        {
            if (SessionFactory == null) //not threadsafe
            { Configuration config = new Configuration();
                 config.AddAssembly(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly());
              SessionFactory = config.BuildSessionFactory();
            }
            return SessionFactory.OpenSession();
        }
    }
}
```

fichier App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>

     <section name="hibernate-configuration" type="NHibernate.Cfg.ConfigurationSectionHandler,NHibernate" />

  </configSections>

  <hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
    <session-factory>
      <property name="connection.provider">
        NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider
      </property>
      <property name="connection.driver_class">
        NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver
      </property>
      <property name="connection.connection_string">
        Data Source=HP-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Simulation;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False;
      </property>
      <property name="dialect">
        NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2005Dialect
      </property>
      <property name="show_sql">
        false
      </property>
      <property name="proxyfactory.factory_class">NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle</property>
      <mapping assembly="nhiber"/>
    </session-factory>
  </hibernate-configuration>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup></configuration>
```

class form.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace nhiber
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            try
            {
                utilisateur u = new utilisateur();
                for (int i = 0; i < u.get_liste_utilisateurs().Count; i++)
                    textBox1.Text += "\r\n" + u.get_liste_utilisateurs()[i].name;
            }
            catch (Exception e) { File.AppendAllText(@"C:\Users\HP\Desktop\test1.txt", e.ToString()); }
        }
    }
}
```

but i have this exception :
System.InvalidOperationException: Échec d'instance.
   à System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity)
   à nhiber.utilisateur.OpenSession() dans C:\Users\HP\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\nhiber\utilisateur.cs:ligne 32
   à nhiber.utilisateur.get_liste_utilisateurs() dans C:\Users\HP\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\nhiber\utilisateur.cs:ligne 19
   à nhiber.Form1..ctor() dans C:\Users\HP\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\nhiber\Form1.cs:ligne 21

i need help.any advices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *suspect* this is the problem:

```
 Data Source=HP-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Simulation (...)
```

My guess is that you copied this from a string literal, and that it should actually be

```
 Data Source=HP-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Simulation (...)
```

(Note the single backslash - which is the value you'd get from the *double* backslash in a plain literal in C# source code.)